# Is this integral the same over dual polyhedra of equal volume?

Tags: integration, polyhedra

The integral $$\int_V \frac{d^3x\,d^3y}{|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}|}$$ over various regions $V$ is of interest in physics, where it is related to the gravitational binding energy of an object with uniform density. The best-known case is for a ball. An analytic result is also known for a rectangular cuboid.

I am not aware of analytic results for platonic solids other than the cube, so I have been investing this integral numerically by Monte Carlo techniques. It appears that its value is the same to 3 digits for the dodecahedron and icosahedron, when they have the same volume, which is interesting because these are dual polyhedra. (The octahedron and cube are also dual, but I don't have results for the octahedron because of a bug in Mathematica's RandomPoints function.)

Is there any mathematical argument that this integral should be the same for dual polyhedra of equal volume?

Comment: How far is the result for an icosahedron from that for a _sphere_?

Comment: @IvanNeretin For a unit ball, my Monte-Carlo calculations gave 1.1995 for a sphere (the exact integral is known to be 6/5), 1.1572 for an icosahedron (about about 3.6% less), and 1.1587 for a dodecahedron.

Comment: I guess this is just a coincidence, and the numbers for duals are not really the same.